# PHP, HTML, jquery onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dynamic drop down menu and I need to run a jquery code when the user selects an option.

This is the jquery I need to run:

```
$(function() {

    $("select").on("change", function() {

        var value = $(this).value(); //get the selected id
        $.get("requesturl.php", {
            course: value
        }, function() {

            // do something with the response
        }, "json");

    })

})
```

This is my php code:

```
     if(User('PROFILE')=='admin' || User('PROFILE')=='parent'){


        $sql=  "SELECT id, course_period_id from schedule WHERE STUDENT_ID='$_SESSION[student_id]'";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        $options="";

        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $id=$row["id"];
            $course_period_id=$row["course_period_id"];
            $course= DBGet(DBQuery("SELECT title FROM course_periods WHERE course_period_id='$course_period_id'"));
            $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$course[1]['TITLE']\">".$course[1]['TITLE'].'</option>';

        }


        echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>
                function populate(course)
            {
                alert('test');
             }</script>";


        echo "<SELECT id='course' name = 'course' onchange='populate(this.course)'  >
            <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
             $options

             </SELECT>";


     }
```

I tried to run a test alert inside the jquery but nothing happened when I selected an option.

Please help me, I have no idea how to add the jquery code to my php code.

Comment: change alert(test); to alert('test');

Comment: still nothing changed :/

Comment: write Javascript function instead of Jquery and call it on OnChange event

Comment: where you have written populate function?

Comment: Where is the code where you actually do something with the response of the ajax call?

Comment: The populate function is the test function:
 echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>
                function populate(course)
            {
                alert('test');
             }</script>";

Comment: no, where you put `//do something with the response` you should actually do something there before anything can happen...

Comment: requesturl.php:

$course = $_GET["course"]
if($course){
  //execute Database query and store it in $result
  echo json_encode($result);
}

Comment: lol, no.... do you have any idea what you're doing?

Comment: I still don't know how to add this jquery to my code, this was my question :/
Actually no I have no idea, I'm new to jquery and ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

Java Script Code

```
function populate(obj)
    {
            var value = $(obj).val(); //get the value
            $.get("requesturl.php", {
                course: value
            }, function() {
                // do something with the response
            }, "json");
    }
```

Php Code

```
echo "<SELECT id='course' name = 'course' onchange='populate(this)'  >
            <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
             $options
             </SELECT>";
```

Comment: Write <script> .. your javascript code </script> write this on starting of the page

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $(this).value();
```

this is an incorrect jquery syntax.
use `.val()` instead
eg:

```
var value = $(this).val()
```

and also use

```
 $(document).on(‘change’,’course’,function(){
   // your code on course value change
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
$(document).on("change","course",function(){

    var value = $("#course option:selected").val();

    //......This will returns the selected id

        $.get("requesturl.php", {

            course: value

        }, function() {


            // do something with the response

        }, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have javascript errors, which is why your javascript code is not executing.

You should use developer tools to detect javascript errors in your browser. Usually F12 will open it in Chrome and Firefox.

On the developer tools, you will see js errors - usually on the right corner - with a red cross. Click it to find where the error is.